# Jest not executing express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, routes, jestjs, supertest

I am trying to write tests for a simple endpoint which is protected. I have an `auth()` middleware in place which verifies the `Authorization` header and upon successful verification adds a key `token` to the `req` object.

The problem is that `jest` is directly calling the `getCustomerProfile` controller and skips executing `auth()` middleware because of which the controller says `req.token` is undefined. This is how my Jest setup looks like:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mapRoutes = require('express-routes-mapper');

const privateRoutes = ('../routes/private_routes')
const auth = require('auth_middleware');

const setupAction = async () => {
  const testapp = express();
  const mappedPrivateRoutes = mapRoutes(privateRoutes, 'api/controllers/');

  testapp.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  testapp.use(express.json());

  testapp.use('/private', mappedPrivateRoutes);

  testapp.all('/private/*', (req, res, next) => auth(req, res, next));

  return testapp;
};


module.exports = { setupAction };
```

Below is how I am trying to test the  protected endpoint:

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const {
  setupAction
} = require('./setup_jest');
const Customer = require('models/customer_model');

let test_api;

beforeAll(async () => {
  test_api = await setupAction();
});


....
...
...

test('Customer | get profile', async () => {
  
  let token = 'TestToken123'
  
  res = await request(api)
    .get('/private/customer/get-profile')
    .set('Accept', /json/)
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    .send()
    .expect(200);

  expect(res.body.customer_id).toBeTruthy();
});
```

In `auth.js` I have tried adding `console.log()` statements but it has no effect. Nothing gets printed and the request goes straight to `getCustomerProfile()` controller without validating the authorization headers.

What's more interesting is that when the `express` app is running and I hit the private endpoint with the `Authorization` header using `Postman` it works completely fine and the request goes through `auth()` middleware.

It is only while running through jest,  the middleware is getting skipped!

I am stuck here for hours now. Can anyone please help me out with this? Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: Your `testapp.all('/private/*', (req, res, next) => auth(req, res, next));` should just be `testapp.use('/private/*', auth)` because it is meant to be a middleware and it should be placed after ` testapp.use(express.json());`. I don't think express.all should be used for middlewares.

Comment: @dev I have also tried using testapp.use(), It didn't worked as well